# Field initializer on transient field

Tags: c#, db4o

I am wondering: if I load an object from a db4o database, will field initializers always be called?

An example could be a transient field syncRoot, used for object locking, because of thread-safety:

```
public class Test
{
    [Transient]
    private object syncRoot = new object();

    [Transient]
    private object syncRoot2;

    public Test()
    {
        this.syncRoot2 = new object();
    }
}
```

The db4o query is like:

```
Test mytestObject = (from Test test in session
                     select test).First();
```

I can't use `syncRoot2` because during the db4o query, the object constructors are not called, so the value will be null. But what about `syncRoot`? Is it safe to use field initializers on db4o model objects?

Comment: I don't know anything about db4o, but I do know that syncRoot will always be initialized.  The .NET framework guarantees that field initializers will run before the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends :)

By default no, since db4o will try to avoid calling the ctor and field initializers are executed within the ctor) (at least using C# compiler shipped with VS 2010).

For example, given the following class definition:

```
public class Item
{
   public object o = new object();
}
```

C# compiler will emit IL (for the constructor) similar to:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Item extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
   .field public object o
   .field public notserialized int32 i

   .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
                  instance void .ctor () cil managed 
   {
        .maxstack 8

        ldarg.0
        newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()  // field initializer
        stfld object Item::o // field initializer
        ldarg.0
        call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        ret
   }
}
```

Basically you have two options here:

1. [Enable constructor](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/api/com/db4o/config/ObjectClass.html#callConstructor%28boolean%29) invocations
2. Use [Activated](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/api/com/db4o/events/EventRegistry.html#activated%28%29) event to initialize the transient fields.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the answer, I didn't know that field initializers are internally called within constructor. "Activated" event options is what I needed